# new tag proposal: house-history or building-history

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

At the moment we have a tag [building](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/building).

Since **building** is both a noun and a verb, I think it might be clearer to have the tag be either [building-history](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/building-history) or [house-history](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-history).  If not, I would like to see the current tag be changed to [buildings](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buildings) to make it clearer that the tag refers to a structure.

New users searching for the word "building", who don't know yet how to search for the tag, are likely to get many, many instances of the verb "building".  I would like to see the old tag [building](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/building) direct to the new tag, whatever we choose.

As far as I can see, **House History** is the better-known term, at least in England (note the currently-suspended Twitter chat #HouseHistoryHour and its website [HouseHistoryHour](https://www.househistoryhour.co.uk/)).

However, we might want to choose **building history** instead to make it clear that commercial buildings as well as houses are included.

Should the tag be:

- [building](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/building) (leave things the way they are)
- [buildings](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buildings)
- [building-history](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/building-history)
- [house-history](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-history)

In any case, we need to write advice for the tag we'll use ([building](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/building) doesn't have any) and perhaps make the unused choices tag synonyms to what we finally decide on.

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go ahead and create a tag for [house-history](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-history) as a rename (using the moderator's merge tool) of [building](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/building) and leaving that as a synonym.

I don't think we need to worry about making the other two (yet to be used) tags into synonyms because anyone looking for a "building*" tag will get redirected to [house-history](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-history).